# 1995 Pontiac Grand Am Over-Heating and Cold air from heater, why?

Tags: coolant, pontiac, water-pump, thermostat, grand-am

My grand am is over heating while idling, blowing cold air out from heater and bubbling in coolant resevoir. Replaced thermostat and water pump and bled the valves to get air out and still same thing. Any suggestions on what this may be?

Comment: How do you know it's overheating? Temp gauge, OBD readings, steam from radiator, or just the bubbling in expansion tank?

Answer (score 2):

Bubbling in the coolant reservoir indicates a bad head gasket, while it may not explain the no heat it's time to trade your car in.

Assuming the coolant is full and the engine is up to temp, check your heater hoses if one is cold and the other hot than the heater core is plugged. If both are the same temp than you'll have to look under dash and make sure that the temp blend door functions.